# concept name(s): container of different types which can be used like a type

Tags: inheritance, concepts, type

I am looking for the name(s) of a concept I heard of. I know that it does not exist in many programming languages, but I think it exists at least in C++.

Let me try to explain the concept.

Assume I want to define a generic collection in some programming language, and I want this collection to contain elements of type `A` and type `B`. In object oriented languages like C# or Java I can do this in at least two different ways:

1. Define the collection to contain elements of type `object`.
2. Create a type (or interface) `C` and change the code so that `A` and `B` both inherit from (or implement) `C`. Then define the collection to contain elements of type `C`.

Both ways have their problems:

1. allows me to put everything into the collection instead of just `A` and `B`, which might not be what I want.
2. only works if I can modify the code of A and B.

**And the concept that I am looking for allows a third approach:**

3. define a "type container" `T` which contains both `A` and `B` and can be used like a regular type, so that I can create a collection of `T`.

In this case, I would only be able to put `A` and `B` into the collection, but I would not be required to change the code of `A` and `B`.

The same concept allows defining methods that take either an `A` or `B` as input and process them the same way. E.g. we might want to define a method `Square` which takes an `int` or a `float` `x` and returns `x*x`. With this concept, we would not need to define two methods (one for `int`, one for `float`).

Comment: By "modify the code of A and B," do you mean "inherit from interface C?"

Comment: Yes. This is not always possible, e.g. if I want to build a collection of `int` and `float`.

Comment: You're almost certainly describing a [Tagged Union, Discriminated Union or Variant Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).  C# and Java don't really support them AFAICT.  See [here](http://gsscoder.github.io/2013/04/23/discriminated-unions-in-c/) for a possible workaround, though it appears that inheritance is still required.  You might do some research on *Duck Typing,* which would allow you to use two different types having the same API without requiring an interface.  Also, study the `dynamic` keyword in C#.

Comment: See also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/597854/Duck-Typing-with-the-Dynamic-Keyword

Comment: Possibly related at SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804955/heterogeneous-containers-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856824/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-heterogeneous-containers-with-value-semantics

Comment: [An implementation of Haskell's "Either" type C++](https://gist.github.com/3noch/6024523)

Comment: [The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the concept you're looking for is a [Union Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type).

Contrast this with an intersection type, which is where all elements of your collection would have to inherit from both A and B.

Comment: There isn't much support for them in C# or Java, though ugly hacks do exist.